# BCNF Conditions not clear

Tags: sql, database, bcnf

I read the below where R is the relation schema, X is the set of attributes and A is an attribute in R. Let F be set of FDs. For R to be in BCNF, for every X-> A in F following must hold:

```
1) A is a subset of X
2) X is a superkey
```

In 2), why does X have to be a superkey? Shouldn't the condition be X is a candidate key because I understand that for BCNF, for every non trivial dependency, a key determines some attribute.

What will go wrong if I replace 2) with X is a candidate key?

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example: suppose relation R(X, A, B), X candidate key. 
If you have FD X->A, you also trivially have FD (X, B) -> A, however (X, B) is not a candidate key (it is not minimal), but it is a superkey.